# This RLE decoding function is decoding only the first character, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple program that compresses strings using the RLE algorithm and I successfully wrote the encoding function and thought I had also figured out the decoding function but it doesn't give out a correct output.

```
string RunLengthDecoding(string input)
{
    string decodedOutput = "";
    int secondIterator = 0;
    for(int firstIterator=0; firstIterator<input.length(); firstIterator++)
    {
        string counter = ""; int letterCoefficient = 0;
        if(!isalpha(input[firstIterator]))
            continue;
        else
        {
            counter = input.substr(secondIterator, firstIterator);
            secondIterator = firstIterator;
            istringstream(counter) >> letterCoefficient;
            for(int i=0; i<letterCoefficient; i++)
                decodedOutput += input[firstIterator];
        }
    }
    return decodedOutput;
}
```

If I input "6A" or really any number stuck to any ONE singular character, it works fine. 
Example:

> 6A --> AAAAAA, 77B --> BBBBB.....BBBBB 77 times.

But if I input "6A3B" it spits out "AAAAAA". Or really any number stuck next to the A and any number stuck next to the B, it would still really just print the first character the number of times it was prefixed with, completely ignoring everything after it.

Comment: I think it should be secondIterator = ++firstIterator; instead of the way it is. I just tried it and the results were the same, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something more like this:

```
string RunLengthDecoding(string input)
{
    string decodedOutput = "";
    int secondIterator = 0;
    for (int firstIterator = 0; firstIterator<input.length(); firstIterator++)
    {
        string counter = ""; int letterCoefficient = 0;

        if (!isalpha(input[firstIterator]))
            continue;
        else
        {
            counter = input.substr(secondIterator, firstIterator - secondIterator); // Little change here
            secondIterator = firstIterator + 1; // Add one here
            istringstream(counter) >> letterCoefficient;
            for (int i = 0; i<letterCoefficient; i++)
                decodedOutput += input[firstIterator];
        }
    }
    return decodedOutput;
}
```

Note, this seems to work for basic input, like "6A3B25C", but I have the feeling that certain edge cases will break this, as there are no safety checks.

Comment: I literally tried adding one the first time around and the output hadn't changed which confused the hell out of me and then I decided to restore it to the original condition with no ones added but now when I re-added the one, it worked. I feel dumb.

Comment: Also, this is my first time writing a compression algorithm (hence, the "basic-ness" of it), can you note how or why would this get broken? I'd like to know.

Comment: @Eyad H. Actually you know more than me. I just get the feeling when you run loops like this there's a chance you're missing some corner case, like what happens if the input string has a space or another character that is neither alpha or number, will the istringstream read it properly? Will it throw an exception? I have no clue.

Comment: Nah, you're correct. My Run-Length Encoding algorithm can encode strings with spaces or non-Latin letters, but the decoding algorithm obviously misses this part due to me narrowing it down to only Latin Letters using the isalpha() function. Thank you for bringing it up, I'll see what I can do about at least the spaces part (since the non-Latin part seems a bit too non-trivial for me to get head first into).